# How to run scheduled tasks with a timeout?

Tags: python, heroku

I have a simple app which needs to run for only 5 mins at  :30 mins past the hour. I'm currently using Advanced Scheduler with a 300 seconds timeout and it works very well. But it is not free. You can only run 100 tasks with it. I have tried to use Heroku Scheduler but than I couldn't find a way to stop the code as it awaits for the scheduled jobs and the default timeout is 30 mins. Am I missing something? Thanks.